# RailsRestore Session Data with Session_ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-cookies

During the checkout process all data is stored in session variables until payment had been successful at which stage the data is saved into the database. With our latest integration with a new payment gateway the client is directed to the gateway and then directed back.

The problem however is that when the user is redirected back from the Payment Gateway, a new session is created and all the data is "lost". If I have the session_id of the client before sending him to the payment gateway, and pass this session_id through the process, is there anyway I can restore the previous session with this session_id.

This is: Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure you want to use the cookie_store? With cookie_store the cookie itself already contains all the data, there is no 'actual' session_id (as there is no persistent storage on the server). btw. usually there's a certain limit of data you can save, i think about 4 kilobytes.

Comment: I am using a DB store, and have the same problem. Any idea on how to restore lost session by its ID?